# как выделить только ту кнопку на которую кликнул

Tags: javascript, css, html5

как выделить только ту кнопку на которую кликнул. Она выделятся но если кликну на другую кнопку то та должна сбросить класс active. То есть только одна кнопка должна иметь класс active

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
    
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.add('active')
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение - при клике сперва убираем класс у всех button, а потом добавляем его нужной

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
    
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    [...buttons].forEach((el) => el.classList.remove('active')); //убираем класс
    this.classList.add('active')
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</main>
```

Comment: В современных браузерах в NodeList и так есть встроенный forEach, кстати → https://caniuse.com/?search=NodeList%20forEach.

Comment: А зачем перебирать все элементы? Не проще сразу взять тот, который `active`?

Comment: @De.Minov ещё проще сразу создать `input:radio` и заканчивать. Ведь это точь-в-точь тот функционал, который имеет встроенный radio элемент.